# Facebook User Access Token Security

Tags: android, facebook-login

Is it secure to user the User Access Token to make Graph Api calls directly from the client (in my case Android app)? And as the SDK refreshes the access token for client, token hijacking won't be a major issue.

I am fetching the User access token using the method

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is secure to a a extent to use it, but as far as i am concerned it is better to use JWT for Authentication purpose, in JWT a unique id is generated for your token and we can use that id within the app for all the purposes.